# Circular definition in slice category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am reading Aluffi (Algebra Chapter 0) there he introduces the slice category in a kind of excercise:
[image]
When thinking about it I got confused about the "nature" of the $Z$ (and $A$). Since they are defined to be objects of the class Obj(${\sf C}_A)$ they should be morphisms as well. That seems kind of a circular definition. What am I missing?

Comment: "Since they are defined to be objects of the class Obj($C_A$) they should be morphisms as well." What makes you think that?

The morphisms on this new category he is defining will be appropriate commutative diagrams which have $Z,Z'$ and $A$ on it. Since you have $f$ and $f'$, there is one map missing. So, in fact, the morphisms will be "the obvious diagrams with a map $g: Z \to Z'$ which make the diagram commute".

Comment: Maybe the issue you are having is with the abstraction of the concept of an object and a morphism.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you think is going on, but $Z$ and $A$ are objects of $C$, not of $C_A$.

Comment: Oh cra..., sure!! I thought if $Z$ consists of morphisms from $Z$ to $A$, then it would consists of morphisms of morphisms of morphisms, .... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have missed that $A$ and $Z$ are not objects of ${\sf C}_A$ but only objects of ${\sf C}$, hence there is no circularity in the definition.